# Pandas replace does not replace linebreaks - why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a problem with strings that contain linebreaks. In order to clean them up, I use pandas replace function. However, I am unable to get it to work. I use the following code:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data=['Why does it not go away? \n #whygodwhy'])
test_df.replace(to_replace=r'\\n', value="", regex=True, inplace=True)
print(test_df)
```

Running the code, I get the following output:

```
                                 0
0  Why does it not go away? \n #whygodwhy
```

Hence, the \n does not get replaced and I am unable to find my error. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: have you tried `\n` instead of `\\n`? The `\n` is a special character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r'\\n'` is wrong, if you need `r` flag, you should use `r'\n'` or `'\\n'`.

That is:

```
test_df.replace(to_replace='\\n', value="", regex=True, inplace=True)
```

or

```
test_df.replace(to_replace=r'\n', value="", regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not escape the '\n' character with another '\'. Just do:

```
test_df.replace(to_replace=r'\n', value="", regex=True, inplace=True)
```